# How to set a default value for a hidden field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, frameworks

im working in a project that creates 2 types of users: admin and member. To differenciate them i have set a *bool* value, *true => admin ||  false => member*.

Only admins can create admins, if an anon user tries to create an account, the default value for that field needs to be *false*. I have set a *@html.HiddenFor* in that field, but its sending a null value so the model can't be saved in the database.

this is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Registro(
        [Bind(Include="Id,Login,Pass,Nombre,Apellido,Rol")]Usuario objUser)
{
    //somecode

    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    //error shows the null 'rol' parameter
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Usuario.Add(objUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    return View(objUser);
}
```

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rol)

    //some inputs for the other fields
}
```

Haven't found info related to that
is it possible or do i need to do something else?

Comment: You can set the `Rol` property value in your GET action. But remember, never trust the data coming from client.

Comment: Its like `public ActionResult Reg(){ objuser.Rol=false; return View(objUser); }` Im not really use to working with mvc.

Comment: So what problem are you having when you do that ?

Comment: @Yantup What is you db.Usuario.rol's datatype? is it not nullable? is there any default value assigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suggest you to use this simple way :

you can using viewbag to do this .

In Controller :

```
viewbag.Test="This is a test";
```

In View :

```
  <input type="hidden" id="Test" name="Test" value="@Viewbag.Test">
```

Comment: I think this make more sens for him:

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rol, new { Value = "@Viewbag.Test" })